# DateTime Parse dilemma in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

Been trying to solve this one for hours...

```
string date = "2009-09-23T13:00:00"

DateTime t = new DateTime();
t = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "HH:mm", null);
```

Results in this exception:

System.FormatException was unhandled
Message="String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: But if I want to have a DateTime consisting only of hours and minutes?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
t = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", null);
```

With ParseExact, you're trying to take a string and tell the parser exactly  what format the string is in.  The above line will convert this to a valid DateTime.

If you want to SHOW only the hours and minutes, you would then add the following:

```
string myString = t.ToString("HH:mm");
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to specify the whole string from which it is parsed.

```
DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", null);
```

Comment: ParseExact returns a DateTime or throws an exception (no boolean return). The TryParse methods return booleans.

Comment: @Sean, Webleeuw: Oh yeah, right...got those two mixed up, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to specify a format that does not match the input. `ParseExact` requires you to specify the input format; you cannot simply specify a format indicating which components you would like to extract.

The format you would need to use here is `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"`.

However, given that this looks like an XML date/time format, if it is then you may be better off using the [`XmlConvert.ToDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.todatetime.aspx) method instead as it can handle the subtleties of the XML date format specification.

Comment: XmlConvert was the answer I was looking for (otherwise I'd have added it ;-p)

Answer (score 2):

The documentation says it all:

> The format of the string
>   representation must match a specified
>   format exactly or an exception is
>   thrown.

Your date string does not match the format HH:mm.

By the way, you can leave the = new DateTime(); part away.

Answer (score 1):

ParseExact requires the string to exactly match the format. This one doesn't. You need yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss as your string.